# to apply counters on directories inside a folder

Tags: linux, bash, directory, rename

I've a folder structure like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun 30 21:34 dir_0.0.1_2
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul  2 23:45 dir_0.0.1_1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   24 Jul  3 00:03 a.sh
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul  3 00:04 dir_0.0.1_3
```

a new directory with name : `dir_0.0.1` is created by the script `a.sh` on the same directory.
How can i apply a counter in my script so that the newly formed directory is renamed to `dir_0.0.1_4`?

Comment: Hints: use a `while` loop and test for the existence of directory `dir_0.0.1_${i}` increasing the counter `i` with each iteration and creating the new directory once the test fails.

Comment: Wouldn't you rather have the script create the correctly-named directory in the first place?  Or do you really need to find and rename a mis-named directory?

Comment: @JeffSchaller: no, the directory with name 'dir_0.0.1' is created by untar of `.tar.gz` file, so it's always created with the same name, i just want to rename those with some sequence numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In zsh:

```sh
set -- dir_0.0.1_*(oe['REPLY=${REPLY##*_}']n[-1])
mv dir_0.0.1 dir_0.0.1_$(( ${1##*_} + 1 ))
```

This sets the positional parameters (using only `$1` here) to the expansion of the wildcard `dir_0.0.1_*(oe['REPLY=${REPLY##*_}']n[-1])`:

- filenames must start with `dir_0.0.1_`
- filenames are then `o`rdered (sorted) with the subsequent `e[ ... ]` expression, which
- sets the sort key to the part of the filename resulting from the stripping off as many leading characters as possible until the final `_` underscore
- sorted `n`umerically
- the list of filenames is then sliced to return the last element (`[-1]`)

That filename with the largest current index is now in `$1`. That number is retrieved inside the `$(( ))` numerical expansion (again, by stripping off leading characters through `_`), then one is added and the static prefix is prepended.

In bash, I'd loop through the filenames and manually compare the indices:

```sh
# safe starting point
greatest=-1
for d in dir_0.0.1_*; do n=${d##*_}; [ "$n" -gt "$greatest" ] && greatest=$n; done
mv dir_0.0.1 dir_0.0.1_$(( greatest + 1))
```

A breakdown of the bash loop (sh-compatible, actually):

- we start by setting a presumably-safe starting point for the index -- something that's guaranteed to be lower than anything we find
- use a `for` loop with a wildcard to pick up the existing directory names; for each of those directories:
- capture the index at the end by stripping off everything from the front through the last underscore
- test that index to see if it's greater than the current highest index; if so, reset the highest index
- after the loop is done, rename the directory as above, by appending the "highest + 1" value

Another option is to brute-force loop through the indices until you find an unused one:

```
# set this to something you know exists
index=1
while [ -e dir_0.0.1_"${index}" ]; do index=$((index + 1)); done
mv dir_0.0.1 dir_0.0.1_"${index}"
```

This increments `$index` until the correspondingly-named directory does *not* exist. We then use that unused number to do the rename.

Comment: Thanks, could you please explain the part:  n=${d##*_}; [ "$n" -gt "$greatest" ] && greatest=$n. Would appreciate!!!

Comment: Sure thing @A.K; see the edit above.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, more clearer now.